# Capturing Image from Camera and Upload to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-camera, firebase-storage

I am working on a simple blog app that allows the user to upload photo from phone gallery and descriptions to the Firebase Server. I am trying to modify my current project to allow the user to capture photo from camera and uploading it to the firebase server.

Currently, I am able to display the image that i have captured into imagebutton, however i am unable to post my image to the firebase server (The "submit post" button does not react to my onclick function).

I am suspecting there is some error in my startPosting() function or i did not encode the image correctly? Please help.

```
package simpleblog2.emily.example.com.simpleblog2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.io.File;


public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private StorageReference mStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                intent1.setType("image/*");

                /*
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
                */
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPosting() {

        mProgress.setMessage("Posting to blog...");


        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null) {

            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        // if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      /*   mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)

                    .start(this);

*/

            Bitmap mImageUri = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mSelectImage.setImageBitmap(mImageUri);
       }


        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                mSelectImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: @DaminiMehra Your answer is a new function, so the function is to replace my startPosting() function? What did i do wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question, i realized that i can get my captured data using the function of data.getData() instead of using the Bitmap function:

```
 mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
```

Also, Previously i did not realized that my 'crop' function could not work because i am missing of:

```
mImageUri = resultUri;
```

I realized that there is an issue that if i did not crop my captured image, the fire-base could not handle the high resolution (Or storage size? and it will be loading very slow/image did not appear), This can be resolve by the 'cropping' function.

The final code is stated below:
**Thanks all for your help.**

```
package simpleblog2.emily.example.com.simpleblog2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;


import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;


public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    private static final  int GALLERY_REQUEST =1;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=1;

    private StorageReference mStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
                //startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);


/*
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

                */

            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }



    private void startPosting(){

        mProgress.setMessage("Posting to blog...");


        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null){

            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl =taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      // if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){




        mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);




        /* Bitmap mImageUri1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         mSelectImage.setImageBitmap(mImageUri1);

          Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                  data.getExtras().get("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


*/



        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                mSelectImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
                mImageUri = resultUri;

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }


    }




}
```

Comment: i am getting error in getdownloadurl()
how do i solve it

Answer (score 0):

Before it was if auth != null but I changed it to if true so the if will always evaluate true.

```
  private void uploadFile() {
    //if there is a file to upload
    if (filePath != null) {
        //displaying a progress dialog while upload is going on
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child("Blog_Images.jpg");
        riversRef.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //if the upload is successfull
                        //and displaying a success toast
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        //if the upload is not successfull
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        //and displaying error message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //calculating progress percentage
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                        //displaying percentage in progress dialog
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                    }
                });
    }
    //if there is not any file
    else {
        //you can display an error toast
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class field `mImageUri` is never initialized. You put received bitmap in local field, called the same as the class field.

```
Bitmap mImageUri = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
mSelectImage.setImageBitmap(mImageUri);
```

Therefore, the condition is never true.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null)
```

Comment: I initialize, using private Uri mImageUri = null; but it still give me the same error

Comment: Exactly, you initialized it with null, and then check if it is null. You never overwrite null value, so condition mImageUri !=null never true.

Answer (score 0):

```html
   if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      /*   mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)

                    .start(this);

*/

            Bitmap mImageUri = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mSelectImage.setImageBitmap(mImageUri);
       }
```

There is a chance that your `URI` is `null`. I assume, this is the problem.
Unless you do it somewhere else?

The image might be loaded because the `requestCode = CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE` but NOT `CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE`.

I am going to post below a code I used to do what you ask, but first few things you need to understand.
From android version 7 using Uri.parseFromFile(file) return a error because google want to restrict your access. From now on if you want to get file uri you should use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles)

1. declare permmisions and FileProvider in your manifest:

```html
       
//File provider declaration in manifest.
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.hadas.yotam.manchworkers.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

```html
//in new xml file define the location you need permmision to, the code below give you permmision for any external file.
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

so now when you upload use the global Uri variable if onActivityResault is successful, here is the code:

```html
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24) {
                            String file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
                            File file1 = new File(file);
                            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file1);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        }
```

Then in your onActivityResult you do check if your photoURI = null, if its true (its null)
use photoURI = data.getData();

```html
//if phone android version greater or equal to Marshmelo                    

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

//check if have permmission to write to external + permmision to camera

                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

//if its have permission then new intent to capture image

                        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

//if android version >= 24 (Android Nugget)

                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24) {

//create new String to pictures directory and set the file name to current_time.jpg
                            String file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
                            File file1 = new File(file);

//set GLOBAL variable Uri from the file using FileProvider

                            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file1);

//add the file location the intent (the picture will be save to this file)

                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        }
                            tagIntent = CAPTURE_RESAULT;
//else - dont have permission, request for permission
                    }else{
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAPTURE_RESAULT);
                    }
else - 
                }else{
// same thing only without FileProvider (FileProvider only required since Nugget)

                        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        String file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
                        File file1 = new File(file);
                        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(file1);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
                    tagIntent = CAPTURE_RESAULT;
                }

//if phone can handle the intent, start the intent for resault.

                if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent,tagIntent);
                }
```

Comment: Yes i set it to private Uri mImageUri = null; is this the cause of my error? if so, what should i change it do?

Comment: I did something like what you trying to achive, when I will get home I will upload the relevant part of the code.

Comment: In general you need to get the file path, but getting the url from data might return null (depand on the android version). if you use version 6 or below you can use: mImageUri = data.getData();    If you want to make sure you get Uri I would check if the phone run android 6 or above and if it does add extra to the capture intent adding file location and get the uri from the file.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope its will help you.

the thing is that on phone below version SDK 24 you can just use mImageUri = data.getData() in the onActivityResault but above that it return only a thumbnail and not the entire file (not sure why) so you telll the system WHERE to save the capture picture and then use the file + FileProvider ot get the URI

Comment: i do not get the part  whereby i have to put externalpath, where do i place the code? I went to search online https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html i could not understand where should i place the code too.