# How to put a photo frame images in firebase and then select a photo in which we want to overlay the photoframe?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to develop an application which takes a photo and then the user selects the frame and adjusts/crops the photo. The photos frames are to be uploaded manually to firebase and called in app using the api. Lastly thr user saves the photo to the device and firebase. I dont know where to start at, what concepts or samples should I look at. I did a lot of research but couldnt find. Please help me by recommending the things I should follow and look at. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check camera Permissions
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

check this for crops the photo
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

and check this for upload it to firebase [Capturing Image from Camera and Upload to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376328/capturing-image-from-camera-and-upload-to-firebase)

Comment: thanks, but what about retrieving a frame from firebase and then using it in a picture which we captured.